# is there only one correct weight and bias for neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, genetic-algorithms

I solved the xor problem using neural network... but I'm really confused

my neural network structure looks like this!

[image: structure]

the first result was like...
[image: result1]

and the second result was like...
[image: result2]

could there be multiple answers in weights and bias in neural network? or is it just because of the local minium...
(both two result has **VERY** small cost)

*I used the GA method to optimize the cost function.. I this that could be the reason why I have two totally different answers meaning that those result could be caught on the local minimum.. but please regard that both two result has super small cost*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple solutions to solve the XOR problem using a neural net with the structure you show.  With standard back-propagation training or with a GA, the solution you find will depend upon the initial sets of weights, and how weights are adjusted over the course of training/evolution.

If you run it multiple times, however, what you will start to notice consistent patterns to the signs of the weights and biases.  Doing lots of comparisons you'll notice a symmetry among those patterns as well.

Regarding the cost being small but not zero, if you're using a sigmoid function for the last layer, the output can never truly be 0 or 1, but very close, so your cost will always be greater than zero.

Comment: thanks for the comment! I appreciate it!